# Is there a way to tell composer about manually updated modules?

Tags: updating, composer

I am working on a drupal 8 site and tend to update some modules:

1. I run the `composer outdated 'drupal/*'` command and it shows me the list of modules need update.
2. Running `composer update drupal/module_name --with-dependencies` end up with discard changes output.
3. So I choose to update the module from admin interface, after updating db changes, the status report not shows any update anymore but running `outdated` command in composer list the modules again.

This means I somehow need to announce to composer about this manual update (I think by changing composer.json and/or composer.lock, but I did not find the flow of it, yet.

Comment: Why are you doing this? What do you mean by "end up with discard changes output"? Why don't you discard them then? You know about the discard changes config in your Composer file and the `-n` flag?

Comment: For #2 maybe the module is set to a fixed version number in your composer.json which would explain why it doesn't update to the lstest version.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in the sense if you want to hack `composer.lock` you can make Composer think it got updates it never downloaded.

That requires you to know what `composer.lock` properties have changed (like `content-hash` & `packages[*]`) and apply them manually to the file.

That said, doing this is breaking the entire purpose of Composer (`composer.json` represents a manifest of what you need & `composer.lock` represents a manifest of what Composer retrieved); you
 run the risk of breaking of what `composer.lock` should do (i.e. `composer install` on any machine will retrieve the exact same files as when you made your last updates); so you 
 should really think about the impacts on other environments/hosts that use your `composer.*` files.

If you're committing to a Composer-driven process, it's better to troubleshoot why your dependencies aren't updating as other commentators have suggested (e.g. too broad versioning in `composer.json`, auto-dropped changes from a non-interactive run)